# SQL SERVER DATA TOOLS WITH TFS INTEGRATION

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, sql-server-data-tools

I want to use ssdt with tfs but there is no team explorer menu in ssdt.Most of people suggest to use visual studio community edition to do it.
I want to use SSDT without Visual Studio but use with TFS ,is there any way to do that?

Comment: The SSDT 2017 installer includes TFS integration. It's currently in preview and can be installed from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt

Comment: @Bilgehan You need to install the [Team Explorer 2017](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2017/04/05/team-explorer-for-tfs-2017/), See this article: [SQL Server Data Tools 2017 and TFS Integration](http://sqlkover.com/ssdt-2017-and-tfs-integration/)

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: no.

You would need to install at least Team Explorer (ie. TFS Client Tools) to use TFS, but that does include the VS shell.

The other option would be to use TFS to host git repositories and thus avoid the need for a TFSVC client. You would need a git client (eg. https://git-for-windows.github.io/), but that can be from the command line.